# Python Pandas and regex in replacing items in Dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Hi I am trying to remap a Dataframe using a dictionary in Python Pandas but I need to use regex to make things work fine.

Here is a sample of the dict:

```
di_cities = {
"Ain Salah (town)": "Ain Salah"
"Agadez town": "Agadez"
"Bamako city":  "Bamako",
"Birnin Konni town":  "Birni N Konni",
"Konni":  "Birni N Konni",
"Kadunà":  "Kaduna",
"Kaduna (city)":  "Kaduna",
"Kano (city)":  "Kano"
"Matamey":  "Matamey",
"Mopti city":  "Mopti"
"N'guigmi":  "Nguigmi",
"Tunis":  "Tunis",
"Tunis (city)":  "Tunis"
}
```

I am using this iteration:

```
di_cities = {rf"\b{k}\b": v for k, v in di_cities.items()}
df_cities_clean = df.replace(di_cities, regex=True)
```

As you can see in the pic (final result) it works fine for Bamako, Agadez, Mopti and every sigle-word string. Doesn't for any string with parentheses and in case of Birnin Konni messes up a little bit.
I am using another dictionary in a similar way but there every string is between parentheses and `{rf"\({k}\)"` works perfectly.

Can you help me?

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2oBN.png)

Comment: Use `re.escape`. `\b` won't help then.

Comment: Try `di_cities = {rf"\b{re.escape(k)}(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))": v for k, v in di_cities.items()}`. Note that it may not work if your dictionary has overlapping keys (those that are prefixes of other(s)). This also assumes your keys always start with a word char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! It's almost perfect to me! It does the job for everything except Konni i.e. overlapping keys (there is just this one at the moment) but I solved with a workaround

Comment: what result do you need? Maybe you should simply `split(" (")` and get first element

Comment: Thank you furas but I cannot split patentheses from the string as I need to normalize how city names are spelt: eg. 'Tunis (city)' -> 'Tunis'. Of course I could reach the result in some other ways but applying the dict would make it easier

Comment: Do you really need to run it on all columns?

Comment: Please clarify once you are online.

Comment: Yes, I need to perform the change in all columns because I will aggregate columns in different ways for a GIS analisys. Well, I could remap each column separately or combine them and then splitting again but remapping in one time would be faster. Anyway, your solution works, if you write it in an answer I would flag it as best answer

Comment: Great, next time, please add `@username` mention in the comment to notify this user of your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
di_cities = {rf"\b{re.escape(k)}(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))": v for k, v in di_cities.items()}
```

With this dictionary comprehension, you create another dictionary with keys as regular expressions matching former keys as whole words that *start with word characters* (that is, digits, letters, underscores, connector punctuation) and - if they end with word chars - are not immediately followed with another word char. If a key does not end with a word char, say, if it ends with punctuation, or whitespace (maybe adding `.strip()` would make it safer), no additional boundary check is applied.

The `rf"\b{re.escape(k)}(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))"` escapes [all special regex metacharacters in] the key first, and then prepends it with a word boundary, and `(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))` is a non-capturing group that matches

- `(?<=\w)\b` - a word boundary if the preceding char is a word char (`(?<!...)` is a positive lookbehind)
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\w))` - no additional check (empty string is matched) if there is no word char immediately to the left of the current location (`(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! That works perfectly. You've been very clear in your explanation too.